# Mock view helper in Zend Framework 3 in PHPUnit test

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, zend-framework3, view-helpers, zend-servicemanager

I want to test a specific controller action in Zend Framework 3. Because I use `ZfcUser` (https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) and `Bjyauthorize` (https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) I need to mock some view helpers. For example I need to mock `isAllowed` view helper and let it return true always:

```
class MyTest extends AbstractControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(include 'config/application.config.php');
        $bootstrap      = \Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
        $serviceManager = $bootstrap->getServiceManager();

        $viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');

        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(IsAllowed::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $mock->expects($this->any())->method('__invoke')->willReturn(true);

        $viewHelperManager->setService('isAllowed', $mock);

        $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->setAllowOverride(true);
        $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->setService('ViewHelperManager', $viewHelperManager);
    }

    public function testViewAction()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/myuri');
        $resp = $this->getResponse();
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        #$this->assertModuleName('MyModule');
        #$this->assertMatchedRouteName('mymodule/view');
    }
}
```

In my `view.phtml` (which will be rendered by opening/dispatching `/myuri` uri) I call the view helper `$this->isAllowed('my-resource')`.

But I got response code 500 with failing exception when executing `testViewAction()`:

```
Exceptions raised:
Exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'A plugin by the name "isAllowed" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\View\HelperPluginManager' in ../vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:131
```

How can I inject my `isAllowed` mock to the view helper manager in a way, that let the test case (`testViewAction` / `$this->dispatch()`) pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the previous answer already, we need to override the ViewHelper within the `ViewHelperManager` in the application object. The following code shows how this could be achieved:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->setApplicationConfig(include 'config/application.config.php');
    $bootstrap = \Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
    $serviceManager = $bootstrap->getServiceManager();

    // mock isAllowed View Helper of Bjyauthorize
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(IsAllowed::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $mock->expects($this->any())->method('__invoke')->willReturn(true);

    // inject the mock into the ViewHelperManager of the application
    $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager')->setAllowOverride(true);
    $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager')->setService('isAllowed', $mock);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewHelperManager is an other instance of service manager. and it's not allowed to override [source code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/blob/master/src/ServiceManager.php#L60). Can you try "setAllowOverride" before "setService" method?